# Group by options in a cross tab report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crosstab

I have a cross tab report in Crystal 2008 (ver 12).  First column has a name and second as a phone number.

If there are two individuals with the same name, the report seems to combine the two cells and only show the name once (its like two rows have been merged into one such as in Excel). Both numbers however are shown correctly in two separate rows.

How can I show the name twice and not have it merged or group together?

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8bTz.jpg]]

Comment: Can you show crosstab options

Comment: Sure, but I can't see an 'add photo' or 'add attachment' option when responding in the comments (sorry this is my first post).   If there's a way to add a photo I can share a screenshot of the crosstab options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cross Tab works fine because it's the same name (and cross tab put's it in one group row/column). To separate it, you have to make your column/row by some id_column of that person, but display name instead of that id_column.

For example you put your field in row/columns (id of person, not name),

[image]

and then press `Group Options` and set the name to be displayed

[image]

And that should do it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome! Just tried the steps above and it's no longer grouping it by the name. Thanks!

One followup question, after making the change, the names are not sorted in ascending order anymore. I'm guessing it's because I'm now using the person_id field.  To have the list sorted by name, I'm guessing I have to use the 'Use a Formula as Group Sort Order' option - thoughts?